# Why am I getting null in Console?

Tags: java

Should generate a random password based on how many characters you want in the password. It does create a password, but shows as Password: **null**bjkalhmmglmhb . Not sure why null comes out, but still creates password.

```
   import java.util.Random;

        //26 letters in alpha
        public class PasswordRandomizer {
            int length, position;
            String password;
            Random random;

            public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
                this.length = length;
                random = new Random();

                for (int counter = 0; counter < this.length; counter++) {
                    position = random.nextInt(length - 1);
                    char symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(position);
                    this.password = "" + this.password + symbol;
                }
            }

            public String createPassword() {
                return this.password;
            }
        }

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PasswordRandomizer randomizer = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
            System.out.println("Password: " + randomizer.createPassword());

        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @Pshemo -- I figured that it was a common dup, which is why I answered with a community wiki. In other words, I was too lazy to look for the dup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is null initialy: `String password;`, and then you concatenate Strings to this null variable -- not good. Use a StringBuilder or first initialize the String to a non-null value before concatenating Strings to it: `String password = "";` would do.